# Pandas - updating sequence of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this Sample DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={1:[0,3,4,1], 2:[4,1,0,0], 3:[0,0,1,2], 4:[1,2,3,4] })

   1  2  3  4
0  0  4  0  1
1  3  1  0  2
2  4  0  1  3
3  1  0  2  4
```

But i want to convert it to the format below:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={1:[1,1,1,1], 2:[0,2,0,2], 3:[0,3,3,0], 4:[4,0,4,4] })

   1  2  3  4
0  1  0  0  4
1  1  2  3  0
2  1  0  3  4
3  1  2  0  4
```

Is there any way or a function to do this as i have more than 100,000 rows so for loops, dictionaries, lists won't work.

Comment: what do you mean by format?

Answer (score 3):

My entry:

```
data = df.reset_index().melt("index").query("value > 0")
out = data.pivot("index", "value", "value").fillna(0).astype(int)
```

giving

```
In [273]: out
Out[273]: 
value  1  2  3  4
index            
0      1  0  0  4
1      1  2  3  0
2      1  0  3  4
3      1  2  0  4
```

Unfortunately you'd have to clear the index and column names if you want to get rid of them, using either `df.index.name = df.columns.name = None` or `df.rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, 1)` or something.

Answer (score 2):

Using `get_dummies`:

```
s = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=df.columns, prefix_sep='', prefix='')
out = s.groupby(s.columns, axis=1).sum().drop('0', 1)
out.mask(out.ne(0)).fillna(dict(zip(out.columns, out.columns))).astype(int)
```

```
   1  2  3  4
0  1  0  0  4
1  1  2  3  0
2  1  0  3  4
3  1  2  0  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `zip` and `np.isin`

```
pd.DataFrame([ np.isin(y, x)*df.columns.values for x , y in zip([df.columns.values]*len(df),df.values)])
Out[900]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  0  2  0  4
1  1  2  0  4
2  1  0  3  4
3  1  0  3  4
```